# Does Site.createPortalUser work in test class?

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-portal

I am writing a test class to test SiteRegisterController.cls. But registerUser is returning null during testing. What could be the problem? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm

The test class is clearly documented here.repeating for clarity

```
 // Test method for verifying the positive test case 

static testMethod void testRegistration() {
    SiteRegisterController controller = new SiteRegisterController();
    controller.username = 'test@force.com';
    controller.email = 'test@force.com';
    controller.communityNickname = 'test';
    // registerUser always returns null when the page isn't accessed as a guest user 

    System.assert(controller.registerUser() == null);
    controller.password = 'abcd1234';
    controller.confirmPassword = 'abcd123';
    System.assert(controller.registerUser() == null);
}
```

As mentioned we will get null when the page is not accessed as a Guest User.You may use System.Runas(GuestUser) to resolve your issue .

Comment: Could you please add details on how to create guest user in the above code? I mean what should be the user role, profile and user type for the guest user? I posted similar question here(http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96859/site-createportaluser-returning-null-in-test-context), Could you please look into this if you have time? Appreciate your time. Thanks!