# Site.createPortalUser return null in apex

Tags: community, lightning-experience, customer-community, customer-portal

`Site.createPortalUser(user, accountId, pwd, true)` returns `null` in Apex executing with system administrator.

I need to test creation customer community user with system admin for already created contacts.

Below is the code:

```
public static void createuser(String conId){
        Contact conObj = [Select Id, Account.ownerId, Email, FirstName, LastName, AccountId  from contact where Id =: conId];
        Profile pObj = [Select Id from Profile where name='Custom Customer Community User' limit 1];
        User usr = new User(
            username = conObj.Email + String.valueof(math.random()).substring(0,6),
            FirstName = conObj.FirstName,
            lastname = conObj.Lastname,
            ContactId = conObj.Id,
            Alias = conObj.FirstName + conObj.LastName,
            email = 'dev175@gmail.com',
            communityNickName = 'killportal' + String.valueof(math.random()).substring(0,6),
            profileId= pObj.Id,
            TimeZoneSidkey = 'America/New_York',
            Localesidkey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey ='ISO-8859-1',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        
       String userId ='';
        try{
            userId = Site.createPortalUser(usr, conObj.AccountId, null, true);
            System.debug(userid);
        }catch(exception e){
            System.debug(userId);
            System.debug(e.getmessage());
        }
        
    }
```

Things I have already verified:

1. Account Owner has a role
2. Account is partner enabled.
3. Has an active community.

Comment: Try using Site.createExternalUser() instead. That is the newer recommended method.

Comment: Check similar [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96859/site-createportaluser-returning-null-in-test-context)